# What kind of script can I use to update an application?

Tags: backup, restore

Lets say I am updating an application and have updated 10 files out of a 100. I made these changes on my test machine and is working but now I want to commit these changes to the production machine. What kind of option do I have.

Ideal scenarios would be.

1. I save the existing files that I am replacing
2. I copy new files over the old.

If the changes does not go well, I can reverse the process and restore the old files. What is the best way of doing it. Lets say I am talking about an ASP.NET application. I will also be updating SQL statements, but I can take core of that in separate SQL Script and not worried about that in this update.

I am familiar with Batch scripting but is there a better way of doing it, which has a GUI (Ok I can can create a GUI application and run the batch file from GUI).

Any one who has done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description makes it sound like you want to control your revisions. Use a [Revision Control System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) like [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) or Git (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29).

At a high level, once you make changes to your code, you check those changes in and get a revision number that specifically identifies the most current state of the files at that time (e.g. revision 17). You could then switch to your production server and update the set of files to revision 17 and then compile/whatever. If all does not go as planned, it is easy to revert to any previous version (say revision 15, which was on the production server before you checked out and built revision 17).

A good RCS will manage all your files so that they are "backed up" and can you can restore the code/binaries/config files/whatever you had at any given time by referring to its revision number.

Comment: That's a good point but i want a simpler solution as required by the managers. They want something easy which they can do and undo, like install an update. If it did not work, uninstall it. The installation will simply be copying files to different location.

Comment: This probably the closest answer but I wanted something of a program that will do the installation/upgrade. Perhaps that will be too complicated. An SVN might come in handy.